# Elasticsearch AND Query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE __account_id = 5 AND __import_id IN [1,2,3]
```

Here is my ES query:

```
body = {
    "query": {
        "filtered" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "__account_id" : account.id,
                    "__import_id": [x['id'] for x in ingested_imports]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results seem to filter only on __account_id but not on __import_id. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap a `term` and `terms` filter in a `bool` query because both clauses must match.

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "bool":{
          "must":[
            {
              "term":{
                "__account_id":5
              }
            },
            {
              "terms":{
                "__import_id":[1, 2, 3]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I just noticed that it works fine using my python client but doesn't work from kopf. Not sure what that's about.